# My Toshiba's fans do not work automatically

Tags: kernel, fan, toshiba-satellite, fancontrol

My Toshiba Satellite m505-s4940's fans do not turn on automatically, so it was overheating before I learned how to do it manually by using this keyboard-shortcut:<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

I have to do this every time I use my computer!

I really like the performance of Ubuntu, and I just began to use and love it, but I would like to solve this problem.

Hopefully someone can help me, and sorry about my English. It is not my native language **: )**

Answer (score 4):

This has been [reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/500666) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1282161) and [here (kernel)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14695).

There appears to be [one workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/500666/comments/43):

1. Boot up
2. Suspend
3. Wake it up
4. ACPI should work (fans should work, the lid should sleep it, etc)

If this doesn't work, I recommend you don't run Ubuntu until it's fixed as letting it overheat is very dangerous to the hardware.

Of course if you can help the kernel devs find a fix for this, the faster you get the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toshiba utils Certain Toshiba's laptops to control fan speed.

http://www.buzzard.me.uk/toshiba/index.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem, this fix solved it completelty
http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/08/how-to-control-fan-speeds-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.